# Embed fonts in css

Tags: css

I am trying to use custom fonts in the css file, the code seems to be correct, but the fonts do not display correctly

```
@font-face {
 font-family: K 10;
 font-style:  normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 src: url(Kcustom.eot);
}
```

Comment: Is the eot file present? 100% sure?

Comment: EOT is for Internet Explorer only, is that what you're checking in?  What did you generate the EOT with (application and source)?

Comment: removed .eot and put in .ttf, works in ff and chrome, .eot does not work with ie though

Comment: @reisio if you could put your comment as an answer I could accept the same.

Answer (score 5):

Fonts that contain spaces or special characters in their name must be enclosed in single or double quotes.

Comment: Which browser are you trying this in? I believe .EOT fonts are only supported in Internet Explorer whilst Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera do .TTF and .OTF fonts.

Comment: Removed .eot and put in .ttf, works in ff and chrome, .eot does not work with ie though

Comment: .EOT fonts must be created using Microsoft's Web Embedding Fonts Tool, so it's likely that it wasn't before if you were simply able to change the extension and have it work in the other browsers. WEFT download: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/WEFT.mspx and @font-face browser support: http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=%40font-face_browser_support

Comment: Oh I agree. It's an old tool for which there are some alternatives. Web based version of the tool reisio linked to: http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi